# Algorithms new variable with same name

Tags: algorithm, variables

I want to define a new variable called : **character** , with type of **character**

How can i do that without errors? (despite they have the same name)

I tried this on paper : variable character: character, but i am not sure if its correct or not

Thanks.

Comment: All depends on the programming language... I'm quite sure paper does not give you compilation errors.

Comment: What language is this? and can you not obviously use something simple like `ch`

Comment: its not a programming language , our teacher asked us to make new variable 'character'
and the type of it is character 
we have write the algorithm on paper then we translate it to pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your programming language. Like in java you use-
char character = 'A';
And in c-
char character;

Comment: so if i am writing the algorithm on french language , and i want to translate it later to pascal ( the type of variable is CHAR) 
i have to  write in the algorithm variable : CHAR rather than caractère ?

Comment: no the commands are the whether in French or Pascal or any other language make the description in French but the command will be the same that I have shown in answer